# How to multiply each number in array by 2 in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array with characters, numbers and float values.

```
 a[] = {'a',2,2.5}
```

I have to multiply each integer and float by 2 and no operation should be done on character.

My solution -

```
def self.double_numbers(input)
        input.map do |input_element|
            if input_element.is_a? Integer
                input_element.to_i * 2
            elsif input_element.is_a? Float
                input_element.to_Float * 2
            end
        end
    end
```

It is not working, for input

```
   a[] = {'a',2,2.5}
```

It is returning

> 0 4 4

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an array, it should be something like `a = ['a',2,2.5]`. And what would be your expected ouput?

Comment: I think the output is supposed to be `['a', 4, 5.0]`. But how does that method even run without error? Is there a `to_Float` method? (As opposed to `to_f`.) And why would you need to call `to_i` or `to_f` if you've just established that it's an `Integer` or `Float`?

Comment: Your issue is with map in that every item in the array will be tested, so if there is no matching test it has assumed that a character will default to zero.  So either add a test to leave characters untouched or use something like each and then return the new array.

Comment: Where do you get `to_Float` from? Why do you use `self` here? And how have you managed to get a return value from an invalid structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `map` and over each element in the array check if is `Numeric`, and if so, then multiply it by 2, then you can compact your result for `nil` values:

```
p ['a', 2, 2.5].map{|e| e * 2 if e.is_a? Numeric}.compact
# => [4, 5.0]
```

If you want to leave the elements which won't be applied the `*2` operation, then:

```
p ['a', 2, 2.5].map{|e| e.is_a?(Numeric) ? e * 2 : e}
```

Also you could use `grep` to simplify the checking, and then map your only-numeric values:

```
p ['a', 2, 2.5].grep(Numeric).map{|e| e*2}
# => [4, 5.0]
```

I don't know the side effects of doing this, but looks good (of course if the output won't be only Numeric objects):

```
class Numeric
  def duplicate
    self * 2
  end
end

p ['a', 2, 2.5].grep(Numeric).map(&:duplicate)
```

Or also:

```
p ['a', 2, 2.5].grep(Numeric).map(&2.method(:*))
# [4, 5.0]
```

Comment: What if you wanted the output `['a', 4, 5.0]`? i.e., leave the strings unchanged

Comment: In such case modify the `if` statement `p ['a', 2, 2.5].map{|e| e.is_a?(Numeric) ? e * 2 : e}`, also removing the `compact` if you want to to leave them too.

Comment: That is awesome. Why the `e.is_a?(Numeric)` vs the first `if e.is_a? Numeric`?

Comment: @dawg `is_a?` requires a class or module passed to it. In the ternary you _have_ to write `e.is_a?(Numeric)...` otherwise `e.is_a? Numeric ? e*2 : e`, reads as `e.is_a?(Numeric ? e*2:e)` for which the bit in the parenthesis returns a string or number instance, not a module/class.

Comment: `duplicate` is a poor choice here, `double` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You're right @iceツ, as I didn't like how it looks I have never tried it.

Comment: @dawg `e.is_a? Numeric ? e * 2 : e` means `e.is_a?(Numeric ? e * 2 : e)`

Answer (score 2):

> I have to multiply each integer and float by 2 and no operation should
>   be done on character.

here you go:

```
> a = ["a", 2, 2.5]
> a.map{|e| e.is_a?(Numeric) ? e * 2 : e}
#=> ["a", 4, 5.0]
```

**Note:**  `a[] = {'a',2,2.5}` not a correct syntax for array.